# String being empty still gives True value

Tags: c++, file-io, eof, getline

The code is used to implement Max-Heaps using Binary Heaps, and the output is instead 1000 unwanted lines.

```
auto input = ifstream(filename);
string line;
getline(input,line);
while(!line.empty())
{
    int option;
    int in;
    stringstream l(line);
    l >> in;
    option = in;
    switch (option)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            cout << getMax() << "\n";
            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            while(l >> in)
            {
                insert(in);
            }
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            cout << extractMax() << "\n";
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            filled = -1;
            while(l >> in)
            {
                insert(in);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    getline(input,line);
}
```

The input value of the File is:

```
1 6 2 8 12 3 7
0
2
2
0
1 11
0
3 5 15 12 7 9 13 35
2
2
2
```

Upon debugging, the while condition `(!line.empty())` returns a true value after the file is over. I have tried replacing it with `(line != "\n"), but the error persists. What could be the cause of the error?

Comment: `while(getline(input, line))` -- Any reason why you are not doing something as simple as that?  There is no need for a `getline` at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: Yes, the while `(getline(input, line))` works, though why does the other cause an error, if it does the same?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  It would have to be `while(getline(input, line)) { if(line.empty()) break; ...`  but yes, that would be more robust.

Comment: Instead of guessing what `line` is, why don't you examine it? (You could use a debugger or stream it and its size to `std::cerr`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to "they do the same thing" comment. Not quite. If getline fails the string is left untouched (in this case).

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>


int main(int, char**)
{
    std::ifstream is("some invalid file name"); // nonsense
    std::string s = "Hello World";              // any value will do

    std::getline(is, s);
    std::cout << "s = " << s << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

This should print `s = Hello World`. I think the general rule is that once a stream fails then all bets are off. Hence, checking the stream state after each operation is the way to go as recommended by the commenters.